# How can I populate a date object for a struts2 action in a jsp form?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I know how to populate object with simple types (int, String) but how can I do this for a date value???

My class (called `User`) has an attribute called `date` of type `java.util.Calendar`, is there any way to populate this field automatically on a html/jsp form?

My form:

```
 Date: <input type="text" name="user.date">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dates - uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request

[struts2.0.14](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html)

Also take a look at the custom converter example

try and implement a custom converter

```
public class MyConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       Date date = sdf.parse(values[0]);
       //do some validation on class and other stuff
    }

    public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
       return sdf.format(o);
    }
 }
```

then register it with

```
user.date = com.xyz.MyConverter
```

in a properties file
    **MyAction-conversion.properties**

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:date name="user.date" format="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

here  the user.date is of Date type not checked with Calendar. please check